# Unable to load database to the web framework by using flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to retrieve the database from a .db file into web framework by using flask. However, the database is not shown on the web framework. Any suggestion to improve my code? My code look like this:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template 
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mcu_aurix_git.db') 
c = conn.cursor()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():    
    cur = c.execute('SELECT * FROM mcu_aurix')    
    return render_template('flask.html', rows = cur.fetchall())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My flask.html file:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>project</th>
            <th>branch</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>subject</th>
            <th>owner name</th>
            <th>owner email</th>
            <th>owner_username</th>
            <th>url</th>
            <th>commitMessage</th>
            <th>createdOn</th>
            <th>lastUpdated</th>
            <th>open</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>current_date</th>          
          </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for row in rows %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{project_name}</td>
                    <td>{{branch_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{id_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{subject_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner_email}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner_username}}</td>
                    <td>{{url_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{commitMessage_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_createdOn}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_lastUpdated}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_open}}</td>
                    <td>{{status_name}}</td>
                    <td>{current_date}</td>
                  </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

The error shown is :

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 8072 and this is thread id 8352.
```

Answer (score 0):

creating a single cursor object and then using the object whenevr the url hit is bad idea nd will give error.

what you can do is, whenever the endpoint hit then you can get new cursor object

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template 
import sqlite3

def connect_db(db):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db) 
    return  conn.cursor()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():    
    db ='mcu_aurix_git.db'
    c = connect_db(db)
    cur = c.execute('SELECT * FROM mcu_aurix')    
    return render_template('flask.html', rows = cur.fetchall())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I try this method also, but couldn't work. Is it correct I use the command set FLASK_APP=app.py and flask run to execute my code?

Comment: export FLASK_APP=app.py and flask run follow the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/)

Comment: Any suggestion to improve my code since my code is still not working? Thanks.

Comment: The error shown is jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: flask.html